# How to get a string from the user with JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, scope, console

I want to get a string or any value from the user over and over again with JavaScript console. For example something like this, but in JavaScript:

```
int number;

do {
   scanf("%d", &number);
} while (number>0 && number<10);
```

Furthermore I want to work with that data in the global scope. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried reading a line from `process.stdin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the readline module:

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

blocking on input like the above scan is not easy in node, so try the below

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
rl.setPrompt('Enter Number:');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', function(input) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(input)) && input > 0 && input < 10)
    { 
       global.InputNumber = input;
       rl.close();
    }
    rl.prompt();
}).on('close',function(){
    console.log("Number Entered: " + global.InputNumber);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

to set global variables:

```
global.var1 = 'bar';
```

more info:

http://inspiredjw.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js-javascript/